# Javascript Global variable problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

First I know WebKit do not allow Make synchronous requests to SQLite database. And I'm start playing with it and tried to assign result to global variable "data". I still not sure if it's possible but want to ask you.

1. I'm created global object to store respond from DB

   ```
   var data = {};
   ```
2. Here is DB class

```
var db = {
        mydb: false,
        init: function () {
            try { 
                if (!window.openDatabase) { 
                    alert('not supported'); 
                } else { 
                    this.mydb = openDatabase('test_db', '1.0', 'Test DB', 1024*1024*5); 
                }
            } catch(e) { 
                // Error handling code goes here. 
                if (e == INVALID_STATE_ERR) { 
                    // Version number mismatch. 
                    alert('Invalid database version.'); 
                } else { 
                    alert('Unknown error '+e+'.'); 
                } 
                return; 
            }
        },
        exec: function (query, params) {
            try {
                this.mydb.transaction(function(transaction) {
                    transaction.executeSql(query, params, db.dataHandler, db.errorHandler);
                });
            } catch(e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        },
        dataHandler: function (transaction, results) {
            // Handle the results
            data = results.rows;
            return true;    
        },
        errorHandler: function (transaction, error) {
            // returns true to rollback the transaction
            alert('Code: '+error.code+'\nMessage: '+error.message);
            return true;
        },
    }
```

1. And finally here is the problem:

```
$(function () {
    db.init();
    db.exec('SELECT * FROM errors;');
    alert(Log.object_toString(data) ); // this alert show empty object as I declared in first line 
    alert(Log.object_toString(data) ); // this one return object with responded data from database
});
```

So the problem is I can't manipulate with "data" right after db.exec() call, but if I make alert() after transaction then data will populate with all information.

Any ideas how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that you're making an asynchronous <s>AJAX</s> call, so your `alert()` fires before the response is received.

**EDIT:** *As @Nick noted, this is not AJAX, but is an issue with it being asynchronous.*

I don't know anything about the API you're using, but it would seem as though your alerts should be inside the `dataHandler` method:

```
dataHandler: function (transaction, results) {
    // Handle the results
    data = results.rows;
    alert(Log.object_toString(data) ); 
    alert(Log.object_toString(data) );
    return true;    
},
```

Or should be in some other function that is called from inside `dataHandler`.

```
dataHandler: function (transaction, results) {
    // Handle the results
    data = results.rows;
    someFunction( data );
    return true;    
},

// ...

function someFunction( data ) {
    alert(Log.object_toString(data) ); 
    alert(Log.object_toString(data) );
}
```

The reason an `alert()` in between makes it work, is that the pause gives the response a chance to return before  the other alerts run.

Comment: This is HTML5, no AJAX involved, but it is asynchronous :)

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Was a shot in the dark. I've really got to get up to speed on HTML5. :o)

Comment: It looks like he's using a local database. Not that it matters, it's still asynchronous. I think `exec` should accept a callback function parameter which it passes on to its subordinate functions. *Edit:* Nick beat me to it :p

Comment: @Bart - it does accept one, that's the `db.dataHandler` part of the `.exec()` signature :)

Comment: But the db object's exec does not support it atm.

Comment: I just inserted alerts for example. The main idea is to work with respond data any time outside of "db" object. I just want to avoid 10 similar transaction in future.

Comment: @Serhiy - If you need different functions to manipulate the data for different circumstances, then it probably shouldn't be hardcoded into the `exec()` the way it is now, but rather `.exec()` should have a parameter to receive whatever function that needs to do the manipulation. If that's the case, see [@Daniel Baulig's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158865/javascript-global-variable-problem/4158960#4158960).

Comment: Solution: I just move dataHandler function outside of db object. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you access data right after you called exec the dataHandler callback wasn't called yet. The only way to make sure that you actually received your data from the query is to handle it within the callback itself. For that you could redesign your class a bit to allow the exec function to actually also take a callback function that will be called as soon as the query was executed successfully, eg

```
exec: function (query, params, onSuccess /*, onFailure*/) {
    try {
        var onFailure = arguments[3] || function(){};
        this.mydb.transaction(function(transaction) {
             transaction.executeSql(query, params, onSuccess, onFailure);
        });
    } catch(e) {
        onFailure(e);
    }
}
```

Then you can call your db.exec like this:

```
db.exec('SELECT * FROM erros;', null, function(rows) {
    alert(Log.object_toString(rows));
}, function() {
    var error = arguments[0] || {message: 'Unknown Exception'};
    alert('An error occured: ' + error.message);
});
```